# PHP - Apply code to subpages

Tags: php, joomla

I have this code:

```
<?php $url = JURI::getInstance()->toString();
if ($url == "http://example.com/news/latest/"){
  echo "This is latest page";
} else {
  echo "This is not latest page";
}
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is instead of 'http://example.com/news/latest/', how can I select the pages/items under /latest/. If it makes any more sense, here's a syntax:

```
if ($url == "http://example.com/news/latest/" + ANYTHING UNDER THIS)
```

I cannot use not equal to ($url !=) since it will include other parent pages not equal to /latest/. I just want what's under it. If anyone understands it, I need help on how to put it into code.

**Update:**
What I'm trying to do is if the page is example.com/news/latest, it will echo "Latest". And if for example, I am in example.com/news/latest/subpage1/subpage2, it will echo "You are in a page that is under Latest." Anything beyond "Latest" will echo that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = 'example.com/news/latest/dfg';

preg_match('/example.com\/news\/([^\/]+)\/?(.*)/', $str, $page);

if(isset($page[2]) && $page[2])
    echo 'You are under: ' , $page[1];
elseif(isset($page[1]))
    echo 'At: ' , $page[1];
else
    echo 'Error';
```

Edit: after clarification switched to regular expression.

Comment: It echoes the same string for IF and ELSE. What I'm trying to do is if the page is http://example.com/news/latest/, it will echo "Latest". And if for example, I am in http://example.com/news/latest/subpage1/subpage2/, it will echo "You are in page under Latest."

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
$matches = array();
if((preg_match('#http://example\.com/news/latest/(.*)#', $url, $matches)) === 1) {
    if(strlen($matches[0]) > 0) {
        echo "You're at page: $matches[0]";
    } else {
        echo "You're at the root";
    }
} else {
    // Error, incorrect URL (should not happen)
}
```

**EDIT: Fixed, untested so you may have to tweak it a little**

Comment: It echoes the same string for IF and ELSE :/

Comment: It's not changing the string just answering the question.
But I would just check for the substring if it is fixed, no need to use regex as far as I can tell.